# Automapper Mapp from Interface to Interface

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, automapper

public I´ve got a Concrete Mapping from BusinessObject to DatabaseObject but within the Dbo there are some References which are also Dbo´s but with there Interfaces. So when I add a mapping as `cfg.CreateMap<IBo, Dbo>();` The sub-reference cannot be resolved because there is no mapping from `IDbo` to `Dbo` I think:

Example:

```
public class BO1 : IBO1 
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public IBO2 BO2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IBO1 
{
    string Test  { get; set;}
    IBO2 BO2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IBO2
{
    int Some { get; set; }
}

public class DBO1 : IDBO1 
{
    public string Test  { get; set;}
    public IDBO2 BO2 { get; set; }
}


public interface IDBO1 
{
    string Test  { get; set;}
    IDBO2 BO2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IDBO2
{
    int Some { get; set; }
}
```

Now I´ve got the following mapping:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<IBO1, DB1>();
            cfg.CreateMap<IBO2, DB2>();
        });
```

But this throws an not mapped exception. So how can I mapp nested interfaces?

EDIT:

The exception I get is as followed:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
ObjectProxy -> IDBO2
Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy -> Models.IDBO1

Destination Member:
BO2
```

Comment: Are those properties on `DB01` meant to be private?

Comment: Show us the complete `Map` call, source objects included.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, don't use interface references here, use the concrete classes. The issue will be that when creating a DB01, this tells Automapper that it wants an IDB02 for the BO2 and you've only told Automapper how to convert an IB02 into a DB02.  not an `((IBO2)B02)` into an `((IB02)DB02)`

You can use a shared interface between your Entity and DTO/ViewModel if you want to use that as a contract to ensure that they are kept identical (or at least conforming to the same subset of members) but inside the ViewModels, the relationship references should be ViewModels, and within the Entities the relationships should be Entities. This risks breaking Interface Segregation as it's likely that DTOs and entities are *not* purely interchangeable and pretty soon there would be properties or methods added to the interface that apply to one and not the other. Plus it would be dangerous to have something like a DB01 reference a B02 or B01 reference a DB02. These entities should *not* be interchangeable so their references should be concrete.